# react-native init not working for react-native 0.57.1 on windows

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

I am using react-native-cli 2.0.1 and react-native 0.57.1 on windows 10.

However, when I create a project with react-native init projectname and try to run it with react-native run-android I get this error:
[image]

I tried the steps that it mentions except for the first one, because when I try to run it I just get watchman: command not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yarn add @babel/runtime`.
This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: I did but it still didn't work. I tried all the steps that the error in the image mentions except for the first one.